# jQuery,and other library right order to include?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a Wordpress theme that uses MooTools and jQuery. I use jQuery `noConflict` to avoid conflicts with other JS libraries; this didn't help me.

Can someone help me with the right order of including JS libraries on my Wordpress theme?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh dear! Though it can generally be made to work, jQuery+other-framework has a number of problems, and it's a lot of code to include just for a theme. I would always try to avoid multiple frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is add this before your jquery code :

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

and replace all JQuery `$` by `jQuery`. For example :

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
```

Comment: You can also just use `jQuery(function($) { ... });`, or `(function($) { ... })(jQuery)` if you don't need to wait for the DOM to be ready.

Comment: I also create plugin that use jquery,but a lot of themes use mootools,so I have problem with js conflicts.Tnx for replay