# load-scripts in wp-admin theme options file, wrong order, how to change it

Tags: wordpress, load, admin

I have set up a coda bubble information popup in my wordpress theme admin panel which is working perfectly when I put the  code in my theme-options.php file.
I included it in the functions.php like it should and it is loaded in the admin panel:

```
// De scripts enkel voor admin  
if (is_admin()){
            wp_register_script( 'bubble', NHP_OPTIONS_URL.'js/bubble.js');
            wp_enqueue_script('bubble');
        }
    }   
    add_action('init', 'register_js');
```

The problem is, wordpress is already loading some scripts, and this before my script:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&amp;load=jquery,utils,farbtastic&amp;ver=3.4.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/newtheme/options/js/bubble.js?ver=3.4.1'></script>
```

-> here Farbtastic works but not my info bubbles.

When I unload Jquery and let it load right before my code, the bubbles work, but not farbtastic.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&amp;load=utils,farbtastic&amp;ver=3.4.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js?ver=3.4.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/newtheme/options/js/bubble.js?ver=3.4.1'></script>
```

How can I solve this please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not the real answer but a pointer where to look:

[`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)(and [`wp_register_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script)) has an `depends` argument. It is used to determine the load order.
[`wp_deregister_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script) will clear a registered script, even ones registered by other pieces of code.

de-register the other scripts, re-register them with the 'depends' in your order.

Maybe you need to cut your script up in pieces.
Take a look try stuff, if you don't get it ask.

Comment: I know what you would like to explain me I think. The problem is that the order of those scripts in the first line are define by wp-admin/load-styles.php so the problem is I can change them for my site, but not for all sites. If someone installs my theme, it won't be applied.
In the comments from the site where I took the code from (the bubbles)they say that for wordpress it has some conflicts.
But there should be a tooltip somewhere on the net that doesn't conflict with wordpress I guess. Now, I only need to find it :-/

Comment: can't you at least use the (firebug) console to see where the errors come from?

Comment: If I load Jquery at the very first line of my amdin page, then bubbles.js and afterwards I let wordpress load the scripts including Jquery, both bubbles and farbtastic are working perfectly.
But now I have 2x Jquery loading on the page, I really need to sort out how to load my js manually I think.
Firebug show me no errors :/

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I have found my answer here, this has solved my problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534977/jquery-and-other-library-right-order-to-include